# Custom hostname for Cloudflare for SaaS gives Cloudflare 522 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, cloudflare

**Background**
I've built a Rails app on Heroku where I allow teams to set up a customer portal where their customers can login to interact with them. By default the team set up a subdomain, for example subdomain.saastool.com, and this is where their customers access their portal.

I have now built out the ability for teams to use a custom domain/hostname instead of a subdomain. For example, they could direct their customers to portal.customerdomain.com instead of subdomain.saastool.com. I've tested locally on lvh.me and other domains by modifying my etc/hosts and the logic of my application appears to work as expected.

**Enter Cloudflare**
I've set up an account with Cloudflare and have moved my DNS over there. I've followed the instructions outlined on this page:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-for-platforms/cloudflare-for-saas/start/getting-started/#step-1--create-fallback-origin-and-cname-target

All of my original DNS records appear to be working fine (ie my app.saastool.com, subdomain.saastool.com and [www.saastool.com](http://www.saastool.com) all appear to be working). I have added the various DNS records on my end, added a custom hostname, and set the DNS for portal.customerdomain.com on that domain's DNS.

**Problem**
When I visit "portal.customerdomain.com" I get the error "Connection timed out Error code 522" with the Cloudflare branding. Whether I set the CNAME on "portal.customerdomain.com" to the fallback origin, or the CNAME target as specified by Cloudflare, either way I get the same error.

I'm pretty confident that the issue lies within my Cloudflare DNS set up since the domain routing works locally.

Even if I just directly visit "proxy-fallback.saastool.com" I see the exact same error. This makes me suspect that the IP address in the "content" that Cloudflare provides could be wrong, or meant as an example or something like that. I really don't know.

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, I gave up on Cloudflare and went with www.Qloaked.com instead.